# Accessing Ruby Server on amazon instance from my browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have started the Ruby on Rails tutorial and am on my first app. I did all of this on an instance I have on amazon web service (aws). A while ago I installed apache on there so when I put in the public address (port 80) it tells me 'It works'. I want to access this server from my web browser at home.

However when I put in the server address :3000 (the port the app should be running at) I get nothing. Do I need to tell the box to open port 3000 or something of the like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the instance's security group to accept traffic on port 3000. Check out [the docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) for more information.